# Access to the Docker containers

Tags: networking, vpn, virtual-machines, docker, virtualbox

For example I have Host Machine `HM` (Mac OS). Inside `HM` I have installed Virtual Box that contains one virtual machine (boot2docker) `VM1` (`192.168.99.1` at my host interface).

Inside `VM1` I have docker's bridge0 interface with addresses 172.17.0.1/16 I have ran two nginx containers on `172.17.0.2:80` and `172.17.0.3:80`

So, if I will use curl inside `VM1` with these addresses I will get an expected answers. Let's say for `172.17.0.2` it will be `Hello, 1 nginx!` and for `172.17.0.3` - `Hello, 2 nginx!`

So the question - is it possible to access these nginx containers from my Mac OS host machine at different addresses? Maybe I can run some kind of VPN?

At the moment I can only expose container's ports inside `VM1` and get access to them from host machine by `192.168.99.1` address.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I find out one simple solution.

I have created an alias for virtual interface at `VM1`. And set up routing in iptables from external ips to the container's ips

Answer (score 0):

You can also expose using different ports with the -p (--publish) docker flag.

Example: `-p 81:80` in 172.17.0.2 container and `-p 82:80` in 172.17.0.3 container.

Also you can setup another nginx to listen in 80 port with configured virtual domains and proxy/forward the requests to the other machines.